# Is there any not bad way to mention something I did not on / for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I write / do things that I think the community might be interested in, but I don't want to spam the community with junk and don't want to be / people think I'm self-promoting. And I'm wondering if there's any good, unobtrusive way to mention such things here.

This came to mind because I recently did an analysis of posting times in the question data here and thought it might be interesting to people, but felt weird about posting it anywhere on the site.

Is there any not-bad way to mention that kind of stuff?

Comment: If it is about the site, mma.meta.se is pretty open so go on. If it is more about mma programming, you are doing well asking and self answering. As long as the topic is clear I don't see any reason to hesitate.

Comment: "an analysis of posting times in the question data here" - sounds like meta territory; go for it!

Comment: @J.M., Kuba just got around to posting. Good to know I'm not committing some faux-pas.